# how do I view current tpm owner in windows?

Tags: windows, disk-encryption, bitlocker, tpm

How do I see if a TPM owner has already been set? All see are examples of how to clear the TPM, reset owner password, change owner. I just want to see if the owner is set and possibly who it is set to. Looking in tpm.msc its not obvious to me whether there was an owner set or not.

Is this possible? How do I know if an owner has or has not been set on the tpm in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example:

```
CD %systemroot%\system32\wbem
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm path win32_tpm get * /format:textvaluelist.xsl

IsActivated_InitialValue=TRUE
IsEnabled_InitialValue=TRUE
IsOwned_InitialValue=TRUE
ManufacturerId=1398033696
ManufacturerVersion=13.12
ManufacturerVersionInfo=50
PhysicalPresenceVersionInfo=1.2
SpecVersion=1.2, 2, 3
```

Comment: Wow so the wmi provider is the only way to view this? Good to know. I'm surprised manage-bde -status doesn't show this